# How to close current window in php codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I give the link with

```
target = _blank
```

for add new one. After adding the item, I want to close newly opened window. I'm using codeigniter for the adding process than now I just redirect the window.

Comment: use javascript: <script>window.close();</script>

Comment: i like the fancybox for this kind of work, because new window open and close are not working cross browser

Comment: i just try with facebox for this. But javascript in popup window is not working properly.